# How add commonsware TouchListView (tlv) library to android project in eclipse

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I try to add the commonsware TouchListView library (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist)  to my android project in eclipse but I don't know how.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not planning on formally supporting Eclipse for the CWAC components until probably the r15 version of the Android Development Tools, as Android library project support in Eclipse is in flux at the moment, particularly with the changes rolled out in the r14 edition of the Android Development Tools.

In principle, you will need to create a new Android project "from existing sources" using the Android new-project wizard. Then, check the Android section of the project properties to ensure that it is marked as being a library project. Then, you can add it as a library to some other project via that project's properties. More details on those steps can be found in [the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).